# Creating charts using macro

Tags: excel, charts, vba

I have a tiny problem with creating a chart by excel macro. Type of chart what i choose is "Clustered Horizontal Cylinder". I wonder how to code macro to format wall of chart. Example, I want wall of chart looks like :
Rotation : X - 0 degree ; Y - 7 degree. 
My English's so bad. Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Record, these are the statements you can make (with the Chart in question Active).

```
Sub Walls()
ActiveChart.Walls.Select
Selection.Format.ThreeD.RotationX = 0
Selection.Format.ThreeD.RotationY = 97
End Sub
```

Comment: yep, I did it. Thank you so much! uhm, one more question. How to check "Right Angle Axes" option. 
Selection.Format.ThreeD.RightAngleAxes = True. It seems not working.

Comment: Try this `Selection.Format.ThreeD.FieldOfView = 0` It wouldn't let me code in right angle axis but that should set the perspective to 0, doing the same idea.